# JQuery scroll to next instance of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollto, scroller

so all I want is to scroll from the current visible class to the next instance of the class.

HTML Looks something like this

```
<div class="container"> 
 <div class="section">
` <p> lorem ipsum </p>
  <a href="javascript:void(null)" class="next"> next section </a>
 </div>
<div>
```

^ Repeat 'x' times

My js:

```
$(.next).click(function(e){
 $('html,body').animate({}, 
  scrollTop: $(this).parent().next().offset().top
  },'slow');
```

});

So obviously that code doesn't work as it just takes you to the next div but I'm quite rookie and would really appreciate some help.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o1wjedd5/

Comment: create a fiddle for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.closest(".container")` inorder to reach the parent container. Then use `.next()`

```
$(".next").click(function(e){

    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop' : $(this).closest(".container").next().position().top
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/69/)

Comment: this works in the fiddle but not working on my end. Must be a problem with my html markup :/

This is the right answer though

Comment: Just noticed that your script takes you to the current tag's div whereas I need it to go to the next div.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Sorry about that. You're answer works perfectly, there was a problem with my compiler hence the code didn't work. just added .next() after closest and it's perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `},` at the beginning of your animate method.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake from me copying from coffee to js